# What are some key differences from TMUX 1.8 and 2.1?

Tags: tmux

I tried to google for this, but I wasn't able to find anything on the differences of 1.8 tmux and the newer 2.1.

Does anyone know what are some key changes and would it be worthwhile to just use 2.1 instead of the older 1.8 tmux version?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES

Comment: General advice when internet searching for this: `<name of product>` + `change log` or `release notes`. Also, it might be better to simply search for the source code, a lot is nowadays hosted or mirrored on github.

Comment: How can try to google for this and not find it? If you search for `tmux changelog` or `tmux changes`, it gets you the information you need as the first answer.

Comment: I did a search for "tmux 1.8 vs 2.1" I'm sorry if I was stupid and not as smart as you to use the word "changelog". As a newbie the word "changelog" is not in their vocabulary to google. I'm sure you were in the same boat when you started.

Comment: This is the reason why stackexchange is going down the hole because of egotistical devs that think everyone should know what they know and not realizing people don't have the proper vocabulary to ask certain questions. In this case, a simple suggestion of *"I think you should use the word changelog"* in your searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever is writing tmux seems to publish quite a good change log of changes between releases. This change log may be found at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES

Also note that tmux is installed by default on some systems (as part of the OpenBSD base system, for example) and that such implementations may have diverged slightly from what's available at the [tmux site](https://tmux.github.io/).

Also note that version 2.3 seems to be the most recent release (at the time of writing).